# What do you call a person who feels guilty?

Tags: adjectives

I have a character sketch that I have to do for an English class, and the character that I am writing about feels guilty for doing something. What would you call her? Please don't say "a guilty person". She is certainly not guilty of doing anything wrong, she just feels as if the thing that she did was wrong.

Comment: This phenomenon is known as 'false guilt'.

Answer (score 2):

**[Guilt-ridden](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/guilt-ridden)** is the term I would use. It implies a subjective feeling of guilt within an individual, rather than being deemed guilty by another party.